# Protractor ignores elementToBeClickable

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I would like Protractor/Jasmine to click on a button as soon as it is available (it's hidden by a notification for some time).

```
var wrench = $('div.ibox-tools.ibox-tools-item.dropdown');
browser.wait(expectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(wrench), 50000).then(function() {
      wrench.click();
});
```

It seems though that Protractor ignores the condition. I get an error:

```
Failed: unknown error: Element <div class="ibox-tools ibox-tools-item dropdown" uib-dropdown="">...</div> is not clickable at point (842, 145). Other element would receive the click: <div ng-switch-when="true" class="toast-message" ng-bind-html="message">...</div>
```

How can that be? It works when I put a long `browser.sleep()` before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I drill down the source code of Protractor `expectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()` does the following

1. it first checks [visibilityOf](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/d74356b809feb0f1342d42622247e233860e30d3/lib/expectedConditions.ts#L188)
2. checking `visibilityOf` means [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/d74356b809feb0f1342d42622247e233860e30d3/lib/expectedConditions.ts#L393), so it checks for the presence (in your case it is in the DOM), it then checks the element with `isDisplayed`
3. `isDisplayed` checks the visibility of the element, with for example the visibility attribute, see [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ed0e30ef5f89a713f5089cf6f40af3cd7c111613/lib/selenium-webdriver/webdriver.js#L727)

According to the source and what you say this is "correct" behaviour, the element is on the page and the element does not have an attribute like `display:none` / `visibility: hidden`. It's only not conform what you expect, because there is an element in front of it.

I would suggest to take a different approach. Can you locate the notification and wait for the [stalenessOf](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf) of the notification and then click on the button?

Hope it helps